# Android Run a method in the current topActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to write a tester routine which will run through many of the methods in my app. I have an Acivity called Friends. I want to start it and then run a couple of methods. This is done from another Class "WebCall" which is called from a GCM broadcast receiver as it happens.

What I would like to write in WebCall is something like...

```
private void systemTest(){
Intent intent = null;
intent = new Intent(Main.getMSContext(),Friends.class);
Main.getMSContext().startActivity(intent);
Class c = getSomethingorOther(Friends); // I need a class instance to run the method?
c.sendTxt(1);
c.sendEmail(1);
c.deleteFriend(1);
c.finish();
```

The difficulty that I see is that startActivity (intent) does not return a class instance. I expect that it is hidden there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good practice to start an activity from another class and then use it's instance, because if you start an activity from antother activity then your current activity will stop work and you can't assure that your lines will be executed.

It's better to start and activity and use `putExtra()` on the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.getMSContext(),Friends.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle(); // Create a new bundle 
b.putBoolean("test", true); // Put test=true inside
intent.putExtras(b); // Add the bundle to the intent
Main.getMSContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Inside your `onCreate()` of the new activity use the following to check if needs to be tested:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    bool test = b.getBool("test");
    if (test) {
        sendTxt(1);
        sendEmail(1);
        deleteFriend(1);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I did (eventually) and of course it works just fine!

Comment: this should be `b.putBoolean("test", true);` up there